# Сортировка по дате рождения (файл)

Tags: c++, файлы, сортировка

Помогите пожалуйста отсортировать по дате рождения. У меня получилось сортировка только по году, а мне нужно по дате рождения.

```
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <locale>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct student_list
    {

    char first_name[15];
    char second_name[15];
    char two_name[15];
        struct
        {
         unsigned int day,month,year;
        } brithday;
    };

int main()
{

    FILE *input, *output;
    int i,n=5;
    char s[255];
    struct student_list bd [10];
    student_list sort[10];
    input=fopen("test.txt","r");
    i=0;
    while(i<n)
    {
        fscanf(input,"%s",&bd[i].first_name);
        fscanf(input,"%s",&bd[i].second_name);
        fscanf(input,"%s",&bd[i].two_name);
        fscanf(input,"%d",&bd[i].brithday.day);
        fscanf(input,"%d",&bd[i].brithday.month);
        fscanf(input,"%d",&bd[i].brithday.year);
        i++;
    }
    setlocale(LC_ALL,"Russian");
    cout<<"\tСписок группы:"<<endl;
    cout<<"--------------------------------------------------------------------------------"<<endl;
    setlocale(LC_ALL,"Russian");
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
        cout<<"№ "<<i+1<<"| Ф.И.О. студента: ";setlocale(LC_ALL,"Russian");
        cout<<bd[i].second_name<<" "<<bd[i].first_name<<" "<<bd[i].two_name;setlocale(LC_ALL,"Russian");
        cout<<"|Дата рождения: "<<bd[i].brithday.day<<"/"<<bd[i].brithday.month<<"/"<<bd[i].brithday.year<<"|"<<endl;
        }
    cout<<"------------------------------------------------------------------------------";


for (i=0;i<n-1;i++)
{

    for (int g=i+1;g<n;g++)
    {
        if(bd[i].brithday.year>bd[g].brithday.year)
        {
        sort[1]=bd[i];
        bd[i]=bd[g];
        bd[g]=sort[1];
        }
    }
}




cout<<"\tСписок группы упорядоченный по возрастанию году рождения :"<<endl;
cout<<"--------------------------------------------------------------------------------"<<endl;
    setlocale(LC_ALL,"Russian");
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)

    {
        cout<<"№ "<<i+1<<"| Ф.И.О. студента: ";
        setlocale(LC_ALL,"Russian");
        cout<<bd[i].second_name<<bd[i].first_name<<bd[i].two_name;
        setlocale(LC_ALL,"Russian");
        cout<<"|Дата рождения: "<<bd[i].brithday.day<<"/"<<bd[i].brithday.month<<"/"<<bd[i].brithday.year<<"|"<<endl;
    }
cout<<"------------------------------------------------------------------------------";
 _getch();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну так Вам нужно только поправить условие при сортировке. Вместо `bd[i].brithday.year>bd[g].brithday.year` написать что то вида

```
bd[i].brithday.year>bd[g].brithday.year || 
  bd[i].brithday.year == bd[g].brithday.year && 
  bd[i].brithday.month>bd[g].brithday.month ||
bd[i].brithday.year == bd[g].brithday.year &&
  bd[i].brithday.month == bd[g].brithday.month &&
  bd[i].brithday.day>bd[g].brithday.day
```

Можно восзпользоваться функциями перевода даты и сделать сравнение в одну строку, но в данном случае это не нужно. Обычно месяцев редко бывает больше 12 (точно меньше 20), а дней в году больше 31 (точно меньше 50). Поэтому, можно сделать так

```
 bd[i].brithday.year * (20*50) + bd[i].brithday.month * 20 + bd[i].brithday.day > bd[g].brithday.year * (20*50) + bd[g].brithday.month * 20 + bd[g].brithday.day
```

Но для серьезного кода все таки лучше воспользоваться функциями декодирования дат.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь, но на первый вариант решения, компилятор ругается (error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment)

Comment: нашел, исправил

Comment: Спасибо большое! Работает!